# update column data based on another columns with new data

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update table record based on the data from another table column,
the concept is I want the table to be updated once there is a new update on grade from user_grades table and this new value should then be updated in t_xp table in a column xp i.e xp=xp + grade; once the page is refreshed the script should check if is there any new update from grade column, if yes then the column xp then should be updated

I tried to write the code, but my code it updates the values at every time, by taking the stored values and added together; so I got stuck here any help please
The followings are the code that I tried with the screenshot of my tables

```
functionupdate_points(){
  $sq_update_pt="UPDATE t_xp p JOIN user_grades ug ON .userid=ug.userid                  
  SET p.xp= p.xp+ug.grade";if($sq_update_pt){
    mysql_query($sq_update_pt);echo"Succssefuly updated";
  }else{
    die("Unable to update: ".mysql_error());
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use a trigger.

Comment: Thanks, let me work on it.